# Как получить ID пользователя в мидлвэйр?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware

class CheckSubscriptionMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    async def on_pre_process_update(self, update: types.Update, data: dict):
        user = types.User.get_current()
        print(user)
```

хотел получить id пользователя, но вместо этого возвращает None, есть ли какой-либо способ получить id, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Думаю так

```
async def on_pre_process_update(self, update: types.Update, data: dict):
    user_id = update.from_user.id
```

Comment: Ну да, без этого невозможно? потому что нужно проверить update это message или callback_query.

Comment: Зачем? У тебя же не Message или СallbackQuery, а Update. И это апдейт точно пришёл от юзера.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код как можно получить id  пользователя который пытается запустить существующий хендлер

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware

class User_id(BaseMiddleware):
     async def get_id(self, msg: types.Message, data: dict):
         print(msg.from_user.id)
```

Что бы вообще по всем сообщениям отображать id пользовтеля можно создать пустой хендлер

```
dp = Dispatcher(TOKEN)
@dp.message_handler()
async def all_mes(msg: types.Message):
    pass
```